# Broadcast receiver to download data and send a notification

Tags: android, download, broadcastreceiver, server

I have a receiver which catches an alarm/system broadcasts and then it has to get the current data from the server and then send a notification. How can I achieve this ? Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Initiate an Intent Service from a broadcast receiver. Download the data with HTTP request from the server. Then parse the response and put the notification accordingly..

```
 public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
       final NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
       final NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
       if (wifi.isConnected() || mobile.isConnected()) {
          Intent intent=new Intent(context,DownloadService.class);
          context.startService(intent);
       }
       else {
          Toast.makeText(context, "No Network Connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
    }
 }
```

DownloadService class:

```
 public class DownloadService extends IntentService{
      String response = "";
      private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
      public DownloadService() {
          super("DownloadService");
      }

      @Override
      protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            // Get the data
            // Parse the data
            // Put the notificaton using NotificationManager
      }
 }
```

Comment: Will the IntentService start running immediately or does it has to wait for the system to schedule it at a later time ?

Comment: IntentService will be called as soon as you receive a broadcast intent

Answer (score 0):

For your problem what you can do is that you can execute AsyncTask which will get data from your server in OnReceive method and when you get success while retrieving data you can set your notification buider over there.

Below code you can use for showing notification

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =   new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher) // notification icon
            .setContentTitle("Notification!") // title for notification
            .setContentText("Hello word") // message for notification
            .setAutoCancel(true); // clear notification after click
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(pi);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```